# Stored PL/SQL function

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I'm trying to implement a stored function in PL/SQL that finds the total number of cities visited by a given driver, return the driving license number.

I tried something like this, but i keep getting "Function created with compilation errors.". The thing is, oracle 11g doesn't show where is the error at?
Here is what i got.

```
create or replace function driverL return number
as licence L#%TYPE;
begin
select L#, count(T#)
from driver d
join trip t ON d.L# = t.L#
join leg l ON l.t# = l.t#;
return licence;
end;
/
```

How do i consider multiple visits to the same city as one visit?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL*Plus you can use the statement `show errors` after the `create` statement to show the compilation errors for the most recently created or altered stored procedure/function/package.

In your code I see at least two problems:

1. You are missing an `INTO` clause in your select
2. The column `L#` in your `SELECT` clause is ambiguously defined since two tables have a column with that name

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how do i consider multiple visits to the same city as one visit?

Comment: in that case use cursor or some collects to hold the data and return that collection!!